# Search and connect bluetooth device from iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am trying to use Bluetooth of iPhone/iPad device from my app and search for near by devices within range and connect to the same.

Like non iOS phone or Mac within range it should show available devices and when tap needs to connect from the app.

I have tried below code using core bluetooth framework:

```
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    _centralManager.delegate = self;

- (void)DidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    //start scanning
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
    
}
```

but no delegates being called. I am running app on iPad 4 and I have LE Android phone (Bluetooth 4.0 LE compliant).

`scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil` I am setting `nil` to show all available devices.

Comment: Can you please add for what version of ios you want to implement this?

Comment: latest... basically i wanted to connect to RFID reader....from iPhone via bluetooth...so to start with i am looking out for bluetooth connection...

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use **[CBPeripheralManager]**.

After setting up delegate, fire **[scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:]** Then in delegate method **[didDiscoverPeripheral]** you will get a name for each peripheral. Then you can show user a list of available devices and then use function **connectPeripheral** in CBCentralManager.

You can find great tutorial written in Objective-C [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor).

Comment: hello, you had mentioned about CoreBluetooth framework. this framework only allows to connect Low energy bluetooth devices. can you tel me please we i have to have app which requires to connect in general all nearby available devices...as what i googled out it i snot possible. is it true or there are ways...we can achieve this?

Comment: There is no such framework which will allow you to do this. As fair as I know, CB framework is the only library accepted by Apple.